# swift firebase get Image from Storage and show in JSQMessage Controller

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I want to get a saved Image in Firebase Storage.

I have the url saved in an string value in the Firebase database:

```
mediaUrl = url!.absoluteString
```

Now I want to get this image.

I observe the messages.

```
func observeMessages() {
    let query = Constants.refs.databaseChats.child(chatId).queryLimited(toLast: 50)

    _ = query.observe(.childAdded, with: { [weak self] snapshot in

        if  let data        = snapshot.value as? [String: String],
            let id          = data["sender_id"],
            let name        = data["name"],
            let timestamp   = data["timestamp"],
            let media       = data["media"],
            let text        = data["text"]?.encode(),
            !text.isEmpty
        {
            if media == "text" {
                if let message = JSQMessage(senderId: id, senderDisplayName: name, date: self!.dateFormatter.date(from: timestamp), text: text) {
                    self?.messages.append(message)
                    self?.finishReceivingMessage()
                }
            }
            else if media == "image" {
                let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(withPath: text)
                storageRef.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) -> Void in
                    if data != nil {
                        let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                        if let imageMessage = JSQMessage(senderId: id, senderDisplayName: name, date: self!.dateFormatter.date(from: timestamp), media: image as! JSQMessageMediaData) {
                            self?.messages.append(imageMessage)
                            print("image message")
                            self?.finishReceivingMessage()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    })
}
```

If the media is an image, I want to create an image bubble, and when text a normal text bubble.
But I get no Image in the JSQMEssageViewController.
What went wrong? Can someone help me there?

I get the url in console:

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/emmessenger-22.appspot.com/o/media%2FJzl0EUmjSvZZcpCd8Mdi8X9q87G2%2F03.06.2019%2021:26:39?alt=media&token=1c45feaf-0ed8-4f88-9c1f-13f4c6a8f3d4
```

And after that I get the following at console:

```
2019-06-03 21:28:21.092580+0200 EMMessenger[38502:554129] [] nw_proxy_resolver_create_parsed_array PAC evaluation error: NSURLErrorDomain: -1003
```

Thanks

Comment: You can use download `URL`  + `SDWebImageCache` library together.

Comment: I think the getData function of Firebase ist correct, the url I have and the url works. But I dont get the Image in a Message Bubble

Comment: You need to use library like `SDWebImageCache` for `UIImageView`.

Comment: To get the Image from the url to UIImage?

Comment: Have a look at [SDWebImage](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage).

Comment: But I think I dont need that for Firebase, havent read that before

Comment: This is not for Firebase. This is something related to loading the image from a live url to imageView without interrupting the UI.

Comment: But that I get in the data variable which I get back from Firebase

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194436/discussion-between-thetiger-and-morri-94).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you don't need to call `getData` function for this case. As you're using `tableView` so I would recommend to use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage) library to load the images on cells asynchronously. Once you have the `imageURL` just call below method

```
yourImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/emmessenger-22.appspot.com/o/media%2FJzl0EUmjSvZZcpCd8Mdi8X9q87G2%2F03.06.2019%2021:26:39?alt=media&token=1c45feaf-0ed8-4f88-9c1f-13f4c6a8f3d4"), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
```

Rest the library will do for you.

Comment: At this tutorial that will only be done with the getData function. Can you check that? https://www.raywenderlich.com/5359-firebase-tutorial-real-time-chat

Comment: They're waiting until the image downloaded then they pass image object to message.image and append the message into array and reload the table. They're not handling everything. Like on the page load if you have media messages list and need to load in the table at once, They're not checking if the image is already being downloaded or already downloaded. That is just a simple tutorial for beginners.

Comment: So its better to do that with your function? And the I set the Image to the Message?

Comment: Yes! Use this library without any doubt.

Comment: Glad you got it yourself. BTW there is a completion block too which gives you the `url1 and `image` both once downloaded. Also please upvote the answer too :)